# How to mix multiple textures in same procedural material

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor, shader-nodes

I'm trying to create a procedural tiled wood texture with several image textures in it.
I am using a brick texture and would like it to output different wood textures on the tiles in it.
It works well with only two brick colours and two images, using the color ramp and mix shader. Unfortunately I can't figure out  how to do it with more than two textures at a time when there is a color gradient. [image]

So I guess im not really trying to mix the textures but rather use them side by side.
Other suggestions that could be a better way to solve this are very welcome.

Maybe there is a way to use the range of brick colors as texture coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build your own mix shader tree :).
No worries, it's really simple.

1. Daisy-chain as many mix shaders as needed
2. *Math > Greater Than* to cut off values (similar to your ColorRamp)
3. Done

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it very much. It works very well.

Comment: Glad it works for you :). I often put it into a nodegroup, to make it easier to work with ;). good luck with your project.